# How to remove (under conditions based on a property) particular vector members while iterating through the vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase

So I have this code:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A 
{
   private:
       int int_prop;
       virtual void someFunc() = 0;
   public:
       void setIntProp(int p) { int_prop = p; }
       int getIntProp() { return int_prop; }
};

class B : public A 
{
       void someFunc() {}
};

int main ()
{
    // initialize vector for the purpose of this demo
    vector<A*> vecA;
    std::auto_ptr<B> obj1(new B);
    vecA.push_back(&*obj1);
    ( *vecA.front() ).setIntProp(15); // set int_prop of 1st item
    std::auto_ptr<B> obj2(new B);
    vecA.push_back(&*obj2);
    ( *vecA.back() ).setIntProp(4); // set int_prop of 2nd item 

    vector<A*>::iterator a_it[N]; // this is the iterator array  
                                             //for vecA
    int k = 0;

    for (vector<A*>::iterator it = vecA.begin(); it != vecA.end(); it++)
    {
       if ( (*it)->getIntProp() >= 10 )
       {
          a_it[k] = it; // store this element
          k++; // increment array index
       } // end if
    }

    // finally delete the stored iterators
    for (int i = 0; i<k; i++)
    {
       vecA.erase(a_it[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It should be noted that I don't want to duplicate the vector, I just want to store some of its' elements for deletion, because just deleting the elements of the vector while iterating it causes runtime errors.

More to the point I get these errors:

```
 Error  1   error C2057: expected constant expression   
   Error    2   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0    
   Error    3   error C2133: 'a_it' : unknown size  
    4   IntelliSense: expression must have a constant value
```

that point to this line of code:

```
vector<A*>::iterator a_it[vecA.size()];
```

EDIT 1~ I should also mention that the condition to remove an item from the vector is based on the value of an int value of property `int_prop` of the class as shown in the added code 
(Note: this is the reason I haven't found my answer in the other Q's)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: [Erase-Remove Idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)

Comment: _"So I have this code"_ No you don't. I can see five unrelated fatal syntax errors right off the bat.

Comment: btw nice memory leaks

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yep, fixed all unrelated errors sorry about that. Please elaborate on "btw nice memory leaks"

Comment: Better. Elaboration: you have memory leaks

Comment: @Mechanic: I'll give you a hint; count your `new`s and then count your `delete`s!